# What is the definition for gamma(double x) and why is it different on two gcc versions?

Tags: gcc, math.h, cmath

Through unfortunate circumstances I have discovered that my standard library implementations  `<math.h>` and `<cmath>`(C++) apparently contain a definition for a function with a prototype like:

```
double gamma(double x);
```

Though I do not see it listed anywhere in the language standard (draft I have access to).

Using gcc v4.2.1 on Mac OS X that function evaluates the same as `tgamma` which is actually the name given to it in the standard. [(reference)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/tgamma/)

But on gcc v4.6.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 that function evaluates to something different.

I don't understand why a function named `gamma` compiles at all, but why is the result not the same between compilers?

Here is a simple test program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
#include<math.h> // or <cmath>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::stringstream conversionStream(argv[1]);
    double input;
    conversionStream >> input;
    std::cout << "gamma( " << input << " ) = " << gamma(input) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run with 1 argument:

```
$ g++ -o gamma_test gamma_test.cpp 
$ ./gamma_test 1.0
gamma( 1 ) = 1
```

But the output on Ubuntu gcc v4.6.3 is 0!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Summary: Historical confusion abounds; avoid `gamma()` and use `tgamma()`.

It's the math library, not gcc (the compiler), that implements these functions. If you're seeing different behavior on MacOS and Ubuntu, it's probably because Ubuntu uses glibc and MacOS uses something else.

There is no function named `gamma` in the ISO C standard library.

There are standard functions called `lgamma` and `tgamma`. Quoting [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (the latest draft of the 2011 ISO C standard) sections 17.12.8.3 and 17.12.8.4:

> `#include <math.h>`
>   `double lgamma(double x);`
>   `float lgammaf(float x);`
>   `long double lgammal(long double x);`
>
> The **lgamma** functions compute the natural logarithm of the absolute
>   value of gamma of **x**. A range error occurs if **x** is too large. A pole
>   error may occur if **x** is a negative integer or zero.
>
> `#include <math.h>`
>   `double tgamma(double x);`
>   `float tgammaf(float x);`
>   `long double tgammal(long double x);`
>
> The **tgamma** functions compute the gamma function of **x**. A domain error
>   or pole error may occur if **x** is a negative integer or zero. A range
>   error occurs if the magnitude of **x** is too large and may occur if the
>   magnitude of **x** is too small.

These functions do not appear in the 1990 ISO C standard. They were introduced by C99.

Quoting the [Linux man page for `gamma`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gamma.3.html):

> These functions are deprecated: instead, use either the **tgamma**(3) or
>   the **lgamma**(3) functions, as appropriate.
>
> For the definition of the Gamma function, see **tgamma**(3).

- ***BSD version**

  > The libm in 4.4BSD and some versions of FreeBSD had a **gamma**() function that computes the Gamma function, as one would expect.
- **glibc version**

  > Glibc has a **gamma**() function that is equivalent to **lgamma**(3) and computes the natural logarithm of the Gamma function.

and an historical note:

> 4.2BSD had a **gamma**() that computed ln(|Gamma(|x|)|), leaving the sign
>   of Gamma(|x|) in the external integer signgam.  In 4.3BSD the name
>   was changed to **lgamma**(3), and the man page promises
>
> "At some time in the future the name gamma will be rehabilitated and
>   used for the Gamma function"
>
> This did indeed happen in 4.4BSD, where **gamma**() computes the Gamma
>   function (with no effect on signgam).  However, this came too late,
>   and we now have **tgamma**(3), the "true gamma" function.

Since `gamma` is not a standard C function, compiling with `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic` or `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic` should produce at least a warning for any attempt to call it.

You should probably use `tgamma()` (or `lgamma()` if you want the natural logarithm) and avoid using `gamma()`.

The C standard doesn't seem to say what the Gamma function is.  The [Linux tgamma() man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tgamma.3.html) does (but if you're trying to use it you probably already know what it is):

> The Gamma function is defined by
>
> Gamma(x) = integral from 0 to infinity of t^(x-1) e^-t dt
>
> It is defined for every real number except for nonpositive integers.
>   For nonnegative integral m one has
>
> Gamma(m+1) = m!
>
> and, more generally, for all x:
>
> Gamma(x+1) = x * Gamma(x)
>
> Furthermore, the following is valid for all values of x outside  the
>   poles:
>
> Gamma(x) * Gamma(1 - x) = PI / sin(PI * x)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! `-std=c99 -pedandtic` is not generating any warning for me with gcc 4.2.1, so that part is no good. The lgamma and tgamma pasted standard blurbs don't really add value because I think they are easy to look up and not at issue.

Comment: Hmm. `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic` (not `-pedandtic`) gives me "warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gamma’".

Comment: oops. typo in my comment, but not in my usage.  I do get the same warning with gcc v4.6.3.

Answer (score 3):

On some platforms (linux and bsd pre-4.2 or so), `gamma` is `lgamma` (the log of the gamma function).  On other platforms (osx and bsd post-4.4ish), it is `tgamma` (the "true" gamma function). This is a historical curiosity.

There's a note about this in the OS X manpages:

> gamma() and gamma_r() are deprecated, and should not be used.  The
>   tgamma() function should be used instead.  Note, however, that on some
>   platforms, gamma() and gamma_r() historically computed the log of the
>   Gamma function, instead of the Gamma function itself.  When porting
>   code from such platforms, it will be necessary to use lgamma() or
>   lgamma_r() instead.

Long story short, just don't use `gamma`.  It's non-standard anyway.  Use the standard functions `tgamma` and `lgamma` instead (or maybe the posix extension `lgamma_r`, which is re-entrant).