# error C2099: initializer is not a constant & warning C4013: 'gamma' undefined; assuming extern returning int

Tags: c

I am trying to use an open source R tree however I get errors. I have spent several hours to fix it but could not. Please help.
The part of the code is as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


#ifndef M_PI
#   define M_PI 3.1415926535
#endif
#ifndef ABS
#   define ABS(a) ((a) > 0 ? (a) : -(a))
#endif

#define EP .0000000001

const double log_pi = log(M_PI);



double sphere_volume(double dimension)
{
    double log_gamma, log_volume;
    log_gamma = gamma(dimension/2.0 + 1);
    log_volume = dimension/2.0 * log_pi - log_gamma;
    return exp(log_volume);
}
```

I get the following errors:
1>c:\users\user\desktop\r\gammavol.c(14): error C2099: initializer is not a constant
1>c:\users\user\desktop\r\gammavol.c(21): warning C4013: 'gamma' undefined; assuming extern returning int

line 14 is const double log_pi = log(M_PI);
line 21 is log_gamma = gamma(dimension/2.0 + 1);

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The two error messages are quite clear.

The first one says that you cannot initialize a variable with a non-constant value.

while `log(M_PI)` is indeed constant, the compiler cannot treat it as such, because it doesn't know if the function `log()` always returns the same result. It does, but the compiler must assume it doesn't, hence "non-constant".

The second one says that the function `gamma` you try to call here is not defined.

Hence, it assumes it is an `extern int gamma()`. As it is unclear where this function is declared, you should at least include the appropriate header file containing its prototype.

Answer (score 0):

This line is the cause of your first error:

```
const double log_pi = log(M_PI);
```

The expression `log(M_PI)` is not constant and cannot be used in the initialization.  Either use the following instead, or move the definition inside your `main` function and remove the `const`:

```
const double log_pi = 1.1447298858494002;
```

The second error is because the compiler cannot find the function `gamma`.  It seems that it is not defined in your `math.h`.  If you're not getting linker errors, I suggest that you add:

```
double gamma (double);
```

The right thing to do would be to find the proper header file to include.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116376/what-is-the-definition-for-gammadouble-x-and-why-is-it-different-on-two-gcc-ve) could shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

`log(M_PI)` is not a constant expression, its a constant qualified object which is not constants in C language terminology. For this you need to declare a named constant you should use either `#define` or `enum`, but not `const` qualifier. **Variables of `const double` type are not constants in C**.

```
#define log_pi log(M_PI)
```

Answer (score 0):

A static const needs to be initialized at compile time, you put a function call there. Advanced compilers such as gcc can compute something like this at compile time anyway and will just warn about the illegal construct instead of erroring out. Yours apparently is not capable of this.

The other thing is that `gamma()` is not a standard libmath function, they are some Unix non-standard thing you would find on BSDs and Linux but not (going by your path names) on your Windows. It is deprecated anyway and there are `tgamma()` and `lgamma()` which are standardized in C99.